# How to synchronize ViewPager with HorizontalScrollView to keep them moving together

Tags: android, android-viewpager, position, horizontalscrollview

I have a ViewPager and a HorizontalScrollView. I would to move HorizontalScrollView in the same position of ViewPager, programmatically, so I would they behave in this way: when I scroll ViewPager to page 1, HorizontalScrollView moves automatically to position 1. I've tried using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and `smoothScrollTo (int x, int y)`, but I don't understand how to use the last method: in particularly, I don't understand what does it mean X and Y in this case. Here the code:

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    HorizontalScrollView hscroll;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        hscroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        hscroll.smoothScrollTo(position-1, position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
```

Any idea? Every help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved in this way, not so elegant and accurate, but it works. Since I've not found a way to get `smoothScrollTo` working, I tried using `smoothScrollBy`, that is a bit different from the first because it scrolls the horizontalScrollView by a certain number of pixels. So, i.e. if we know that the width of every item of our horizontalScrollView is about `72dp`, we can convert dp to pixels programmatically and finally call `smoothScrollBy`. You have also to save the previous position of the last page in order to give the right direction to scroll the horizontalScrollView. Here I show how I have modified the `OnPageSelected` method (`precPos` is an Integer initialized to 0):

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        //hscroll.smoothScrollTo(position, 0);
        hscroll.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

        // convert dp to pixels
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 72, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        // and found the right direction to scroll
        if (position < precPos) hscroll.smoothScrollBy((int) -px, 0);
        else hscroll.smoothScrollBy((int) px, 0);
        // save the last position
        precPos = position;
}
```

I hope this helps if you're facing the same problem. So, I solved in this way, anyway if someone could explain me how I would use `smoothScrollTo`, you're welcome :)