# How to scroll horizontalscrollview and viewpager together

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I want to create an image preview page that have big image which are in viewpager and small images thumbnail which are inside horizontalscrollview. So when I scroll on the horizontalscrollview, one thumbnail (the active image) should move to the middle of the horizontalscrollview and the viewpager should move to the same image which is in the middle of the thumbnail.
I have invested lots of time on it, but it does not work well. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gallery)

Comment: Can you post UI what you want to achieve ?

Comment: go for this link, you get help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145296/how-to-synchronize-viewpager-with-horizontalscrollview-to-keep-them-moving-toget